# With libclang (libtooling), how can I enable and disable specific warnings?

Tags: c++, clang, libclang, libtooling

I'm trying to use the libclang API to programmatically analyze a C++ project.  I have clang compiling fine, and my tool is properly parsing the generated AST, but I can't figure out how to turn on/off specific warnings.

here is the relevant code snippet, I would like to enable/disable the "unused variable" warning:

```
        clang::DiagnosticOptions mDiagnosticOptions;
        mDiagnosticOptions.ShowOptionNames      = 1; // prints warning, ie [-Wextra-tokens]
        mDiagnosticOptions.Warnings.push_back("unused-variable"); // <----- DOESN'T WORK

        // use mDiagnosticOptions further down for compile steps etc.
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is not part of the libclang API (`clang-c/Index.h`). If you're using libclang, then you obtain a translation unit by a call to

```
CXTranslationUnit clang_parseTranslationUnit(
        CXIndex CIdx,
        const char *source_filename,
        const char * const *command_line_args,
        int num_command_line_args,
        struct CXUnsavedFile *unsaved_files,
        unsigned num_unsaved_files,
        unsigned options);
```

You can disable warnings via the `command_line_args` argument, e.g.,

```
const char* const command_line_args[] = { "-Wall", "-Wno-unused-variable" };
```

Comment: The OP's question relates to [libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html), the C++ API, rather than [libclang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html), the C API.  But this answer is useful for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is in the "use mDiagnosticOptions further down for compile steps etc." part of the code.  In particular, if you are using the `LoadFromCommandLine` method of [`ASTUnit`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTUnit.html), you have to pass a [`DiagnosticsEngine`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DiagnosticsEngine.html), which contains a [`DiagnosticOptions`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DiagnosticOptions.html), so naively it seems like you should configure that `DiagnosticOptions` to choose what warnings to enable.

However, `LoadFromCommandLine` parses its command line, and in doing so will overwrite some of the information in `DiagnosticOptions`, such as its `Warnings` and `IgnoreAllWarnings` fields.  (But it does not overwrite `ShowOptionNames`; the details of what survives are not documented, and presumably arise from how the parser is written.)

Therefore, you have to enable and disable warnings using the command line syntax:

```
commandLine.push_back("-Wunused-variable");     // enable one warning
commandLine.push_back("-Wno-unused-variable");  // disable one warning
commandLine.push_back("-w");                    // disable all warnings
```

before passing `commandLine` to `LoadFromCommandLine`.